# php passing key and encrypted CC to another page for processing

Tags: php

I've got a small ecomm form that takes cc information on page 1, does and order review on page 2 and processes the data and cc on page 3.

I'm using a payment gateway and all I'm storing is the authorization code from the gateway.  However, I'm having trouble getting the encrypted data from page 2 to page 3.

I'm using the Sodium library to create a key and nonce on page 2 and then encrypting the cc number and putting that information along with the key and nonce in hidden fields and passing to page 3.

Since the encryption created by Sodium looks to be unicode, by the time it gets to page 3, it seems to have changed plus any quotes the Sodium library randomly puts in the string, causes everything to break and nothing is decrypted.

I've tried changing the page encoding from UTF8 to Windows-1252 but that doesn't do anything.  The actual data in the table looks like the image below.

Given all that, what's the best way to move that data from page to page so I can maintain encryption but still be able to decrypt  the info on the final page?

Just FYI, the encryption in the database can look like:

[image: encrypted data in table]

Whereas the data from the fields looks like

```
b”ç-+èâ¸;ôÞRÛ†`ó¢I+.0?“òÁk
S¯ÉyØ°ðªàB[­±,R­â–îÒÊtH#å¥08Å
ï%Kï8ùM+è@ðgµ%‹3ÒIçüý¡In5H
x¹Xø–ÅÓ>¥4Èbª‚ðˆoµ9…Ÿ‘¸ZMßr§
```

Comment: Store it in a session.

Comment: It's not unicode, it's binary data. You need to use binary-safe methods to store and transmit the data, because if something tries to interpret it as text it's going to be corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

You should not let a credit card number touch your server even to pass from one page to another unless you are fully PCI compliant: https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/faq/

You indicated you have a payment gateway which is a great start. However, any payment gateway worth its salt will provide you with a secure JavaScript method to tokenize the credit card in their system so you only ever touch the token. Then you can store the token locally for use when you have to actually charge their card.

Comment: Ooooh, I didn't catch that bit in the question. Good call.